# Cannot make stacked barplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am trying to make a stacked bar plot in ggplot2 but I am not getting it right. Here is the code for making barplot.

```
ggplot(chr_all_m, aes(chr, value, fill=factor(Genome))) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom="bar", position=position_dodge(0.95)) + 
  labs(x="chromosome", y="kaks")
```

And here is the plot that I am getting it back with this code. As you can see it is not stacked and I thought stacking is the default behavior for most area plots in ggplot2 package. Am I missing something?
[image: ggplot2 barplot]

I even tried removing `position=position_dodge(0.95)` option and the figure I am getting is not correct. Obviously I am doing something wrong here...
[image: ggplot2 barplot no dodge option]

Thanks!

Comment: By including `position=position_dodge(0.95)` you have explicitly told ggplot to dodge, not stack. See the [documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/).

Comment: @joran, please see my edit above in my original post..

Comment: Please re-read my comment and take some time to examine the documentation, in this case `?stat_summary`, where it clearly indicates that the default position is "identity".

Comment: sorry i am missing something here...i tried `position="identity"` but i am getting the same plot as above (2nd plot). But unfortunately the stacking is not correct. As you can see `A01` has three side bars but in the stacked one there is only one.

Comment: Go the documentation page I linked to. Scroll down to the Position section. You've tried dodge and identity, and neither worked. Is there another one that looks promising?

Comment: @jaron Does the documentation change must from version to version? I have version 0.9.3.1 of ggplot2. I don't see any indications on the `?stat_summary` help page about what `position` values are allowed. All it says is "The position adjustment to use for overlappling points on this layer"

Comment: @MrFlick That's why I specifically linked to the web docs, which group all geoms, stats, positions, etc together in a big list, so that the OP could see what position adjustments are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `position="stack"`

```
dd<-data.frame(
    chr=rep(paste0("A",1:3), 3),
    Genome=rep(c("LF","MF1","MF2"), each=3),
    value=rpois(9,100)
)


ggplot(dd, aes(chr, value, fill=factor(Genome)))+
stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom="bar", position="stack")
```

Comment: you are awesome. Thanks for the hint. It worked. How come i can't find the `position=stack` option anywhere. Anyway thanks....